# When I "Mark All As Read" in Google Reader - does this count towards my read items in Trends?

Tags: google-reader

I like using Trends to see my activity in Reader.

When I "Mark All As Read" does this count towards my "Read" items in Trends?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Actually `Mark All As Read` is not affecting your `Trends` at all. From the `Trends` point of view it would be the same if you leave them as `Unread`.

Comment: That seems counter intuitive.  If it's marked as read, why would it increment the Unread count?

Comment: @Owen I changed my answer, because it's actually not affecting at all.. you can run a simple test: check your trends for a specific feed.. and then `Mark All as Read` for that feed to see what is happening with the Trends :)